# How can I specify the initial number of hyperparameter combinations in a hyperband algorithm?

Tags: python, hyperparameters

```
tuner = Hyperband(
    build_model3,
    objective='val_mae',
    max_epochs=200,
    factor=3,
    directory='my_dir',
    project_name='my_project2',
)

tuner.search(x_sub, y_sub, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

In this code, `max_epoch` confirmed that the model is trained up to `200 times` at designation.

But what I want is to explore the same number of `hyperparameter combinations` to compare performance with random search.
If I try 100 random searches, I'd like to have the hyperband pick the same 100 combinations and explore them.

How can I solve this?..